# Construct SQL-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large log table in a database that I need to extract some information from.

The output I'm working towards is:

Day - Attempts - Failed attempts

My table looks something like this;

```
LogID - Timestamp - Sender - Receiver - SecondsConEst - InOut - ErrorMsg - MsgID
```

To extract this error I need to count the MsgID where SecondsConEst is >= 1 and InOut = Out and where the MsgID has been repeated 8 or more times.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT date(timestamp) as Day, count(MsgID) as attempts
FROM database.log 
where Receiver like 'AAB%' and out = 'Out' and (SecondsConEst >= '1' and ErrorMsg != '') 
group by MsgID having count(messageid) >= 8 ;
```

Now this gives me

```
Day           Attempts
2016-02-15    9
2016-02-15    8
```

But I'd like to merge this. If the attempt is 8 or more then it can be called "failed" and should be counted as failed, displaying the total failed that day.

I've tried using

```
count(case when count(MsgID >= 8) then 1 else NULL end)
```

in my select but that gives me "Invalid use of group function".

I'd also of course like to display the total attempts, is it possible to do some kind of inner join for that? Like

```
SELECT (distinct MsgID) inner join where...
```

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Can you add some sample table data and the expected result? (Also, are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?)

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server,  Which one are you using?  Or are you trying to come up with something that works on both?

Comment: Your syntax suggests MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another level of aggregation:

```
SELECT day, SUM(attempts >= 8) as Failures, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM (SELECT date(MIN(timestamp)) as Day, count(MsgID) as attempts
      FROM database.log 
      WHERE Receiver like 'AAB%' and out = 'Out' and
            (SecondsConEst >= '1' and ErrorMsg <> '') 
      GROUP BY MsgID
     ) 
GROUP BY day;
```

Note that this version explicitly selects the minimum timestamp for each message id.  This handles the case when the messages are split between multiple days.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this :

```
SELECT Day,count(case when attempts > 8 then 1 end) as cntFailed FROM(
    SELECT date(timestamp) as Day, count(MsgID) as attempts
    FROM database.log 
    where Receiver like 'AAB%' and out = 'Out' and (SecondsConEst >= '1' and ErrorMsg != '') 
    group by MsgID having count(messageid) >= 8 );
GROUP BY Day
```

If I understood you correctly, all you were missing is another select to wrap your select.